# How can I parse a value (Stepper) from UITableViewCell to main View controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` and a `UIViewController`. In the `UITableViewCell` I have a stepper. How can I make it when user clicked the stepper to send the value to main view controller and receive it in my table view cell?

I tried to get the value from stepper in the cell, but it just doesn't work. My code is bellow.

First: UITableViewCell

```
import UIKit
import HCSStarRatingView
import GMStepper

class FoodsSecoundTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var foodTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodPrice: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodRating: HCSStarRatingView!
    @IBOutlet weak var foodImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var steperCount: GMStepper!
    var result : Double?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        print(steperCount.value) // this line has print the value just one time
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func myStepper(_ sender: Any) { // its a function         
    }

}
```

Second: Main view controller

```
import UIKit

class FoodsViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource {

    var foods = [Foods]()

    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        foods = [Foods(name: "myData", price: 15, count: 0, description: "myData", time: "20 - 30 min", rating: 4, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chick")),
             Foods(name: "myData", price: 30, count: 0,description: "myData", time: "20 - 30 min", rating: 5, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chick")),
             Foods(name: "myData", price: 20,count: 0,description: "myData", time: "20 - 30 min", rating: 3, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chick")),
             Foods(name: "myData", price: 40,count: 0, description: "myData", time: "20 - 30 min", rating: 5, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chick")),
             Foods(name: "myData", price: 55, count: 0,description: "myData", time: "20 - 30 min", rating: 4, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chick"))
        ]

        myTable.rowHeight = 171
        myTable.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return foods.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let food = foods[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foods")  as! FoodsSecoundTableViewCell
        cell.foodImage.image = food.image
        cell.foodPrice.text = String(food.price)
        print(cell.steperCount.value) // the result hear : its print just for one time

        cell.foodTitle.text = food.name
        cell.foodRating.value = CGFloat(food.rating)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good option is using the `Delegate pattern. First, define a protocol that your VC will conform to in order receive the value changed events:

```
protocol FoodsSecoundTableViewCellDelegate: class {
  func stepper(_ stepper: GMStepper, at index: Int, didChangeValueTo newValue: Double)
}
```

Add a `delegate` property to your `UITableViewCell` and call the delegate method whenever value changed on `GMStepper`:

```
class FoodsSecoundTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  ...

  weak var delegate: FoodsSecoundTableViewCellDelegate?

  ...

  @IBAction func myStepper(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.stepper(stepper, at: stepper.tag, didChangeValueTo: stepper.value)
  }

  ...
}
```

Then make your VC to conform to `FoodsSecoundTableViewCellDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: FoodsSecoundTableViewCellDelegate {
  func stepper(_ stepper: GMStepper, at index: Int, didChangeValueTo newValue: Double) {
    print("Value changed in VC: \(newValue)")

    // Process that change...

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FoodsSecoundTableViewCell else {
      return
    }
    // Send the value back to the cell
  }
}
```

Finally, when building your table view, set the stepper's delegate and tag:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let food = foods[indexPath.row]
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foods")  as! FoodsSecoundTableViewCell
  cell.foodImage.image = food.image
  cell.foodPrice.text = String(food.price)
  cell.foodTitle.text = food.name
  cell.foodRating.value = CGFloat(food.rating)
  cell.stepper.tag = indexPath.row
  cell.delegate = self
  return cell
}
```

Comment: How can I send this ( "Value changed in VC: \(newValue)") to my cell in main VC ?

Comment: Just edited my answer. In the `guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? FoodsSecoundTableViewCell` you get a reference to the cell that triggered the value changed. So, you can do whatever needed with `cell` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the example code from [GMStepper](https://github.com/gmertk/GMStepper/blob/master/GMStepperExample/GMStepperExample/ViewController.swift).

In `FoodsViewController`, when you are creating the cell, add a callback to the `steperCount`

```
cell.steperCount.addTarget(self, action: #selector(FoodsViewController.stepperValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

Add the callback function:

```
@objc func stepperValueChanged(stepper: GMStepper) {
    print(stepper.value, terminator: "")
}
```